# Get ClipBoard data from google spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, google-sheets, clipboard

In my WPF application, I can able to get the clipboard data from MS Excel workbook using below code

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsData("XML Spreadsheet"))
{
   var xmlStream = Clipboard.GetData("Xml Spreadsheet") as MemoryStream;
}
```

this above code did not works for Google Spreadsheet. please share any ideas to get the clipboard data of google sheet in code behind.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script is the scripting language you will have to use to run programs in Google Spreadsheets documents.

Unfortunately Apps Script runs on the server side, so it **won't** be able to access the client clipboard data in any way.

### Reference

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)